# How to customize Excel table formatting from C#?

Tags: c#, sql, excel, database

I'm trying to export my data from SQL to Excel table using C#. I already done exporting and create Excel file but now I have a problem formatting the table.

Here is an example data that I already done:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0mgux.jpg)

And I want the table to look like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6cA5C.jpg)

Here are some of my codes:

```
                var excelApplication = new Excel.Application();
                var excelWorkBook = excelApplication.Application.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);

                var xlSheets = excelWorkBook.Sheets as Excel.Sheets;
                var xlNewSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlSheets.Add(xlSheets[1], Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
                xlNewSheet.Name = "Jan";


                DataColumnCollection dataColumnCollection = dataTable.Columns;

                for (int i = 1; i <= dataTable.Rows.Count + 1; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 1; j <= dataTable.Columns.Count; j++)
                    {
                        if (i == 1)
                            excelApplication.Cells[i, j] = dataColumnCollection[j - 1].ToString();
                        else
                            excelApplication.Cells[i, j] = dataTable.Rows[i - 2][j - 1].ToString();
                    }
                }
```

I don't know how to create the customized formatting. Can anyone help me?

Comment: You create a new workboook from scratch. Will it be possible to keep required formatting as a template in an XLSX file, then open and fill it in in the required columns?

Comment: No I want to generate the file everytime the user run it and keep it in that formatting

Comment: Maybe this can help : https://www.e-iceblue.com/Tutorials/Spire.XLS/Spire.XLS-Program-Guide/Excel-Borders-Add-Excel-Borders-in-C-VB.NET.html